# Error, expected a ']' when scanning from txt file to struct in C

Tags: c

I'm getting a strange error and I'm not sure why. I am attempted to scan from a txt file to a struct array and I am getting an error. It expects a ']' after SIZE even though I have a closing bracket for the array length.

Heres the snippet of code that the error is happening in. I am brand new to learning structures so if anything is wrong other than the initial question, please let me know.

Here is the struct definition:

```
struct employData{
char first[7];
char initial[1];
char last[9];
char street[16];
char city[11];
char state[2];
char zip[5];
int age;
char sex[1];
int tenure;
double salary;

};
```

and then here is the scan function that is not working:

```
int readData(employData){
int i = 0;
struct employData dataArray[SIZE];
fp = fopen("payfile.txt", "r");

if (fp != NULL){
    printf("File opened. Scanning...");
    while (!(feof(fp))){
        fp = fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %d %s %d %lf", dataArray[i].first, dataArray[i].initial, dataArray[i].last, dataArray[i].street, dataArray[i].city, dataArray[i].first, dataArray[i].state, dataArray[i].zip, dataArray[i].age, dataArray[i].sex, dataArray[i].tenure, dataArray[i].salary);
        i++;
    }
}
else {
    printf("File open failed.");
}
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: Fixed blatant error. Still having intellisense error

Comment: Does it compile? Does it work as expected? Maybe "intelli" be not so intelligent. Sometimes it happens. 1st make it compile, then take care of warnings.

Comment: What is the definition of `SIZE`?

Comment: I fixed all the errors in `fscanf` and couldn't reproduce the error you're complaining about. It's probably coming from somewhere else in your code -- probably a missing semicolon.

Comment: You know, In C you can split lines in the same places as you can put a space. That can help with readability...

Comment: What is the purpose of the `employData` argument? You're not using it for anything. You also haven't declared a type for it. It's probably a bad idea to use the same name for a variable and a structure type, it gets confusing.

Comment: [`while(!feof(f))` is **ALWAYS WRONG!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm goint to guess here...

You have somewhere a line such as this one:

```
#define SIZE 1000;
```

So the definition of the struct array will expand from:

```
struct employData dataArray[SIZE];
```

to:

```
struct employData dataArray[1000;];
```

And now the error is obvious.

The solution is easy: remove the semicolon from the macro definition:

```
#define SIZE 1000
```

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Learning programming really showed me my ability at making dumb mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've got `%c` in your `fscanf`, which are for single characters, not strings as you seem to have.

Use `%s` for strings instead.

Edit: as @luk32 pointed out to me, `fscanf` needs file pointer as first place parametre.

```
fscanf = (fp, ...);
```

Source: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fscanf/

Comment: Shouldn't `fscanf()` have a file pointer as 1st argument also? =P People are so fast to up-vote incorrect answers lol =)

Comment: @luk32 Yes, missed that. Editing now. Also, I was quick to miss that mistake :)

Comment: Oops, yeah. Dumb mistake on both regards, but I still can't seem to figure out why I am getting the intellisense error regarding wanting the extra ']'?

Comment: Because it's not looking for a pointer, but a single `char`. You provide a pointer to char array, not a `char` which would be indicated by which element of the array you want the char to be placed, which would require `[]`.